# Wordpress discards PNG file when uploading plugin file

Tags: plugin-development, images, uploads

I created a simple WordPress plugin to customize the login screen. The plugin consists of three files:

index.php - adds the actions and filters
functions.php - contains the functions to customize the logo and page

The plugin itself appears to be working fine except that the logo never appears. When I inspect the elements, everything appears fine, but when I go to the plugin editor, it seems the image was never uploaded. I tried moving it from the root folder to an images folder, but it's just not there. It's a small 80x80 PNG with the file name eotb_logo.png.

Any idea why WordPress would strip the PNG file?

Comment: The "plugin editor" - i.e. if you're in wp-admin trying to edit files - may just not be able to handle files that don't contain code. If a PNG were there I'd expect it to be a bunch of odd-looking code just like it looks if you open it in something like Notepad. You can check via FTP whether the file is where you think it is. You can also just type in the URL where it's supposed to be in your web browser.

Comment: I wasn't expecting to view or edit the image, but I would have thought at least the folder and file would appear. I wonder, however, the plugin editor isn't showing the folder because there are no editable files in it. Also, I'm now wondering if the image is not showing because of a security issue.

Comment: That's why typing in the image URL could be useful - you could verify that the file is where you expect it, and users aren't barred from seeing it.

Comment: Tried that. I get a 404 error.

Comment: A 404 indicates the server can't find the file - which wouldn't be a security issue. The path you're trying to call it from probably needs tweaking. It's not really something others could help troubleshoot unless you can share some of the code.